# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while compiling sling

Tags: java, maven, compilation, sling

I'm trying to compile Apache Sling with Maven but I still get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i
n thread "main"
```

I've found that it can be solved by setting MAVEN_OPTS env. variable to this

```
set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

but now I get this error

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried to change it to this

```
set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize512m"
```

but the error is same

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think that the memory initial, i.e-m for megabytes and g for gigabytes has to be capital, so try 'set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"'

Comment: @Dynomyte still the same error

Comment: I set the environment variable MAVEN_OPTS with value "-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M" in windows. After this mvn clean install command works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with Windows's command prompt, but when I used cygwin everything successfully compiled. In many examples are used linux commands and I recommend you to use cygwin.

You should use the following commands:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Comment: Thank you. I've set MAVEN_OPTS and packaged it with -DskipTests parameter and it works!

Comment: Following command worked for me:

`code`
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
mvn clean install -Prelease -DskipTests
`code`

If you have tons of jars included in your pom.xml and you are running thousands of Unit tests, above command shall work for you!